# Can't launch activity from ADB shell

Tags: java, android, adb

Using the command `adb shell am start -a com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.LoginActivity` throws out the following error:
`> Activity not started, unable to resolve intent, flg=0x10000000`

Part of my `AndroidManifest.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/transparent_logo" android:debuggable="true" android:allowBackup="true" android:supportsRtl="true" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory">
        <activity android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.WorkoutsActivity" />
        <activity android:label="Healthy Facts" android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.HealthyFactsActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.WorkoutsActivity" />
        <activity android:label="Help" android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.HelpActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.WorkoutsActivity" />
        <activity android:label="Note Exercise" android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.CatalogActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.WorkoutsActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.ExerciseEditorActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.CatalogActivity" />
        <provider android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.Database.ExerciseProvider" android:exported="false" android:authorities="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit" />
        <activity android:label="Send Feedback" android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.FeedbackActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.WorkoutsActivity" />
        <activity android:label="Workouts" android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.DetailedWorkOutActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.WorkoutsActivity" />
        <activity android:label="Healthy Facts" android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.FatBurnActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.WorkoutsActivity" />
        <activity android:label="Legs" android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.LegActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.WorkoutsActivity" />
        <activity android:label="Abs" android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.AbsActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.WorkoutsActivity" />
        <activity android:label="Butt" android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.ButtActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.WorkoutsActivity" />
        <activity android:label="Core" android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.CoreActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.WorkoutsActivity" />
        <activity android:label="Arms" android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.ArmsActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.WorkoutsActivity" />
        <activity android:label="Strength" android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.StrengthActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.WorkoutsActivity" />
```

So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell am start -a com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.LoginActivity
```

`-a` is for an action string. You do not have an action string on this activity:

```
<activity android:name="com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.LoginActivity" />
```

Instead, use:

```
adb shell am start -n com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit/com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit.LoginActivity
```

(replace the first `com.myfit.sugatmanshakya.my_fit` with your application ID, if that is not already your application ID)

Comment: @Excel: I assume the "n" is for "name", as we are launching the activity by its class name (plus the application ID for identifying which app the activity resides in). But, that is just an educated guess.